# How do I use grep to search subdirectories too?

Tags: grep

How do I use grep to search subdirectories as well as the files in the current directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -rl "string" /path
```

Where:

- **-r** (or --recursive) option is used to traverse also all sub-directories of /path, whereas
- **-l** (or --files-with-matches) option is used to only print filenames of matching files, and not the matching lines (this could also improve the speed, given that grep stop reading a file at first match with this option).

For more informations, `see man grep`.

Comment: For future readers: many command line programs, apart from `grep`, also support the option "work with all sub-files and sub-folders", and that option is nearly-always called `--recursive` or `-r` or `-R`.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -R
```

obviously including your search term.

I can highly recommend reading grep's man-page.  **man grep**

Answer (score 0):

The shortest possible way: rgrep :)